# UITableViewCell which shows subview on touch and hides it on second touch

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, subview

I need to create specific *tableViewCell* ,which shows a special **subview on first touch and hides it on second touch** That subview contains some labels or buttons.

Comment: and your question is? additionally, what have you tried so far, which manuals did you consult and why did your results not work the way you need them to?

Comment: i am new in obj c , so the result of code is terrible,  i don't understand how is right to do this, to add view with controls or to add simply controls , and how to animate appear and disappear of subviews

Comment: I dont understand how it works, I add button to cell using addSubview, and put cell height 50 for example, and button origin.y = 50 , but when i start the app i can see this button instead of it is hidden inside the cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, add a `tag` property to the subview of the cell in question. Also set the subview's `hidden` property to `YES`. Finally, set the cell's `selectionStyle` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.

```
if (thisIsTheIndexPathInQuestion) {
   CGRect theFrame = CGRectMake(...); // figure out the geometry first
   UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:theFrame];
   // further customize your subview
   subview.tag = kSubViewTag; // define this elsewhere, any random integer will do
   subview.hidden = YES;
   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
   [cell.contentView addSubView:subview];
   [subview release];
}
```

Then just react to what you describe in the appropriate UITableView delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (thisIsTheIndexPathInQuestion) {  // you know how to check this
      UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      UIView *subview = [cell viewWithTag:kSubViewTag];
      subview.hidden = !subview.hidden;  // toggle if visible
   }
}
```

Make sure your "special" cell has a different `CellIdentifier` and this will work.